# How to pass an argument in command line to run the script for yarn

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

i'm pretty new to JS. I know that `npm` allows you to use `process.env.npm_config_key` to pass variable in command line like

```
npm run --key="My Secret Passphrase" test:integration
```

But how i can do that using `yarn`?

expected smth like this: `yarn run --key="My Secret Passphrase" test:integration`

Comment: `yarn --key="My Secret Passphrase" test:integration` this should work

Comment: but how to replace 'process.env.npm_config_key' that i use in my function to pick up the key?

Answer (score 1):

You could use standard environment variables:

On the command line,

```
MY_KEY="My Secret Passphrase" yarn run test:integration
```

And in code, read `process.env.MY_KEY`

Comment: unfortunately this approach doesn't work. I tried both ways: MY_KEY="My Secret Passphrase" yarn run test:integration VS yarn MY_KEY="My Secret Passphrase" run test:integration. I placed process.env.MY_KEY in my code though. Getting the error 'MY_KEY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Comment: Did you try directly in your terminal, or in a different way? `yarn MY_KEY="My Secret Passphrase" run test:integration` won't work